# How to gather outputs from joblib.Parallel in Python into one csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have received a previously inactive code to make some changes to the code.
It reads an input csv file, loops over the row, calls a function, and gets an output row which is stored in the output csv file.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

```
def merge_all_rows():
    # some code to merge all csv files in a folder.
    final_output.to_csv('final_output.csv')

def f(row):
    # some code
    output_row.to_csv(f'{index}.csv')

input_df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
    input_rows.append([index, row['a'], row['b'])

Parallel(n_jobs=5, verbose=0)(delayed(f)(input_row) for input_row in input_rows)

merge_all_rows()
```

I didn't like the approach where we are creating one csv file for one row and then finally appending data of these files/row to the final output csv file.

I wanted to try something better so I used a global variable to get all the rows but is didn't work as the global variable was empty at the end of the process.

```
def f(row):
    global output_df
    # some code
    output_df = pd.concat([output_df, current_row_output_df])  

output_df = pd.DataFrame()
input_df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
    input_rows.append([index, row['a'], row['b'])

Parallel(n_jobs=5, verbose=0)(delayed(f)(input_row) for input_row in input_rows)

display(output_df)
```

Can someone tell me a better approach? Not necessarily from joblib.
Any module which provide parallelism

Comment: If you return the "new row" from the function e.g. `def f(row): return new_row` then Parallel will return all these values. You can then create a dataframe directly from the result of `Parallel` e.g. `output_df = pd.DataFrame(Parallel(...))`

Comment: @jqurious okk thanks. I'll try and check.